# How to use webcam in angularCli project?(angular4)

Tags: angular, flash

I used ng2-webcam in my angularcli app but it is giving error:

> ./~/ng2-webcam/lib/fallback/jscam.swf
>   Module parse failed: /node_modules/ng2-webcam/lib/fallback/jscam.swf Une
>   xpected character ' 
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

How to solve this issue? Or how to use integrate webcam in cli project?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an open issue, as is reported here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6226